# how to remove non-relational nested fields strapi V4

Tags: javascript, strapi

I'm using the Query Engine API to return the information I need.

When I request some data, I get the following response:

```
{
"product_name": 'milk',
 "preview": {
            "formats": {
                "xsmall": {
                    "ext": ".jpg",
                    "url": "/uploads/xsmall_drrug_4dc87e7db3.jpg",
                    "hash": "xsmall_drrug_4dc87e7db3",
                    "mime": "image/jpeg",
                    "name": "xsmall_drrug.jpg",
                    "path": null,
                    "size": 2.34,
                    "width": 128,
                    "height": 128
                }
             }
  }
}
```

I want to remove extra fields from the "formats" field and leave only the "url" field there.

I do this but it doesn't work:

```
strapi.db.query("api::product.product").findMany({
populate: {
  preview: {
    formats: {
      xsmall: {
        select: ['url']
      }
    }
  }
}
})
```

I don't know what's wrong, but I think it's because the "formats" field is not built-in, but is generated by the server for different image formats. For any other fields 'select: [...]' works as it should.

How to solve it?